# For loop in batch file with spaces and more than 1 token

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file with this code:

```
    SET /a rotateval = 0
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%A IN ('C:\Users\Max\Google Drive\Misc\MaxPDFcompress\ImageMagick-7.0.9-7-portable-Q16-x64\convert "%%f" -format "%%[w] %%[h]" info:') DO (
            IF %%A GTR %%B SET /a rotateval = 90
```

I'm getting the error that

```
'C:\Users\Max\Google' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried different combos of "delim=" and "usebackq" but to no avail.

Comment: Paths with spaces in them have to be enclosed  in double quotes. There's a space in `Google Drive`.

Comment: As a best practice do not use spaces with variable assignment. In your instance you don't even need to use the `/A` option with the set command.  All you need is `SET "rotateval=90"`

Comment: I tried FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%A IN ('"C:\Users\Max\Google Drive\Misc\MaxPDFcompress\ImageMagick-7.0.9-7-portable-Q16-x64\convert" "%%f" -format "%%[w] %%[h]" info:') DO (
            IF %%A GTR %%B SET /a rotateval = 90  but that resulted in the same error.  Thanks for the tip on the spaces with assignment Sqaushman. Should I edit my question to remove the spaces?

Comment: Make sure your code does not have `ECHO OFF` in the code. Execute the batch file from the command prompt instead of executing it with your mouse.  [Edit] your question with all of the verbose output by copying the text from the console. Please do not post an image.

Comment: If you are still experiencing the exact same error, you must have that path elsewhere in the script unquoted. How about posting the full code so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: I believe that the error you are reporting is absolutely due to double-quoting in the `FOR /F` loop you have submitted geronimo. Assuming that the parenthesized command you have used is correct, the content should look like this `('^""C:\Users\Max\Google Drive\Misc\MaxPDFcompress\ImageMagick-7.0.9-7-portable-Q16-x64\convert.exe" "%%f" -format "%%[w] %%[h]" info:^"')`.

Comment: @Compo, that worked!  Do you want to post it as the answer so I can give you credit.  By the way, I'm not sure I understood why this worked.  Care to elaborate? I see you put an extra double quotes around the whole command while also adding carets?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are reporting is double-quoting related in the parenthesized command within your `FOR /F` loop.

Your submitted content should look like this:

```sh
Set "rotateval=0"
For /F "Tokens=1,2" %%A In ('^""C:\Users\Max\Google Drive\Misc\MaxPDFcompress\ImageMagick-7.0.9-7-portable-Q16-x64\convert.exe" "%%f" -format "%%[w] %%[h]" info:^"') Do (
    If %%A Gtr %%B Set "rotateval=90"
```

The parenthesized command is passed to another cmd.exe instance, and in doing so, it removes leading and closing double-quotes. To prevent that just place the entire command within escaped doublequotes, which when removed will leave your command as needed:

```sh
"C:\Users\Max\Google Drive\Misc\MaxPDFcompress\ImageMagick-7.0.9-7-portable-Q16-x64\convert.exe" "%f" -format "%[w] %[h]" info:
```